# How to print the status of testcases in teardown pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to write a script in pytest where I want to print the status of test result in my fixture teardown:

For example:
there are two test cases

test 1---> fails (print test1 failed in fixture teardown)
test 2---> passes(print test2 failed in fixture teardown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using following hook in your `conftest.py` file:

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    """
    result_setup - setup result
    result_call - test result
    result_teardown - teardown result
    """
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "result_" + rep.when, rep)
```

You can access result of test from fixture teardown like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def some_fixture(request):
    # some setup
    yield
    # teardown
    if request.node.result_call.outcome == "failed":
        print(f"{request.node.name} failed in fixture teardown")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I also want to print if the test case has passed then print the test case has passed in teardown and also is there a way I could return name of multiple test cases which have fialed which the above code?

Comment: You can use following code right after `yield`: `print(f"{request.node.name} {request.node.result_call.outcome} in fixture teardown")`. I believe multiple test cases thing can be achieved using another fixture with wider scope depending on the output you want.

Comment: @pL3b doesn't work if some_fixture fail on its teardown, so you can't get teardown failed state using `pytest_runtest_makereport`

Comment: @storenth where do you want to get information about fixture failure? `pytest_runtest_makereport` is defining `result_teardown` only AFTER teardown.

Comment: @pL3b you never get test's failed state on failed fixture because of `pytest_runtest_makereport`, look: test will pass, but `some_fixture` will fail on its own teardown, so `setup`, `call` reps available, but fixture even know about its failure based on this approach) `pytest_runtest_makereport` will finalise it later on.

Comment: That is true. However you can get `result_teardown` after all fixtures, e.g. in other hooks. By the way, OP wanted to have *test result* status in fixture teardown. Not the teardown status.